# Migrated to new database server, same queries very slow

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb

I have today migrated from my old MySQL server to a new faster one using MariaDB instead.

All fine but larger queries are taking forever to complete (5-10 minutes) when before would take about 10-20 seconds.

I copied across all the settings from my.cnf, don't know what else to do.

I could look at the queries but why would the same query take longer on this newer faster server?

Comment: Did you recreate indices (if you has them)?

Comment: Lots of possible reasons. The first thing to check would be missing indexes. (The question only states "migrated", it doesn't describe the method used to create the replica database.), Really need to look at the EXPLAIN output from the old MySQL database and compare that to  EXPLAIN from the new MariaDB database. Other things to check would be the storage engine used for the tables. Another likely issue might be that the InnoDB buffer pool is much smaller on the new database. Compare "show variables". More i/o contention? Slower i/o? Too many other possible explanations to list in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I've just seen that the variables I've copied over into /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf (as that's where they were), after restarting mysql, haven't got registered in the mysql variables at all. I can try setting the global variable, but will they stay on mysql restart?

Comment: Btw all indexes have copied over, I used mysqldump

Comment: SOLVED! I had to restart the server to make MariaDB pickup the changes in the config files. Annoying as before I had just needed to restart the MySQL service

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I had to restart the server to make MariaDB pickup the changes in the config files, not just restart mysql